# Test for Significance (zero expected values)

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I need a statistical test for significance to see if there is a significant correlation between some genes. No test I have looked at so far seems appropriate.

Problem: A modern species interbred with a subspecies when reintroduced. The subspecies is now extinct and it is estimated that only 2.5% of the modern species nuclear genome is derived from the interbreeding. I have identified 17 genes associated with a disease in a contemporary species 7 of which are found in the DNA of the extinct subspecies. Notwithstanding the fact that only a few samples of the subspecies DNA exist and the estimate of genetic flow I would expect 0 of the subspecies genes to be in the diseased modern species... yet there are 7. Is there a test for significance I could use here?

TIA

Comment: Your statements appear to be contradictory: would you expect $0$ or would you expect $2.5\% \times 17=0.425$?

Comment: Where's the sampling? e.g., did you randomly sample individuals, find 7 of these genes in the random sample, and now you'd like to make inferences about the full population? The mean will not be zero in the population since people can't have negative gene counts and you found positive gene counts.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity,

Comment: Apologies for lacking clarity, I simplified for the non-biologists. I have 17 single nucleotide polymorphisms associated with a homo sapiens sapiens disorder (no negative results in 12 genome wide association studies), 7 of these are also identified in homo sapiens neanderthalensis, 2 of which are common to neanderthals and early humans but not denosivans. Given that estimates are 2-4% of homo sapiens sapiens nuclear DNA is uniquely derived from neanderthal DNA there is an obvious link between the expected and observed values, but how do I prove the significance of this statistically?

Comment: Further clarification due to lack of character allowance... You either have a single nucleotide polymorphism of you don't (binary), thus tests for correlation such as the chi squared test are no good as the expected value would be zero (you cant have a partial 'single' nucleotide polymorphism. Thank you for your reply and hope you can help